# Laravel JWT makes new request insted of sending status

Tags: laravel, api, jwt, laravel-9

I'm making an API in laravel with tymon/jwt-auth package. based on https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

- Login works fine.
- Sending GET request with right token works fine.
- **BUT** when I send a GET request with incorrect/no token it redirects me to POST login (wants me to login) rather than send a 401

GET /api/reviews **with no Auth**:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

**api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group([

    'prefix' => 'auth',

], function ($router) {
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
});


Route::get('reviews',[ReviewController::class, 'index']);
```

**AuthController.php**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return response()->json([
            "user" => auth()->user(),
            "access_token" => $token,
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }
}
```

**ReviewController.php**

```
class ReviewController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
   
    public function index()
    {

        $reviews = Review::all();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'reviews' => $reviews
        ]);
    }
}
```

Should I remove the auth middleware and do it manually?

Comment: are you sending the accepts JSON headers?

Comment: Just tried with Firecamp and got 401, and yes it works after setting Accept header